# Blank square on the right side of the environment

Tags: amsmath

What is the blank square on the right side of the proof? and how to remove it.

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{proof}
Trivial. One can use the $|\hat{\delta}|$ operation defined in Definition to map the original proof for existence of equivalent $\mathscr{T}$ for all $\mathscr{D}$, to show existence of equivalent $\hat{\mathscr{T}}$ for all $\hat{\mathscr{D}}$.
\end{proof}
```

[image]

Comment: That is a common mark for "end of proof", sometimes called the qed symbol (for the slightly more old fashioned "end of proof" mark-Quad Erat Demonstrandem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.), halmos, for the mathematician who popularised it, or a tombstone, because supposedly it looks like a tombstone (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_(typography)). You can get rid of it by doing `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}` in your preamble.

Comment: Fixed the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
This is a common mark for "end of proof", sometimes called the qed symbol (for the slightly more old fashioned "end of proof" mark: "*quod erat demonstrandum*" (what was to be shown) [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.), Halmos, for the mathematician who popularised it, or a tombstone, because supposedly it looks like a tombstone [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tombstone_(typography)). You can get rid of it by doing `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}` in your preamble. The image shows some common alternatives and how to achieve them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}\verb!\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}!
\begin{proof}
No Mark
\end{proof}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\(\square\)}\verb!\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\(\square\)}!
\begin{proof}
White Square
\end{proof}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\(\blacksquare\)}\verb!\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\(\blacksquare\)}!
\begin{proof}
Black Square
\end{proof}
\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{Q.E.D}\verb!\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{Q.E.D}!
\begin{proof}
QED
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can redefine the `\qedsymbol` by writing `\renewcommand\qedsymbol{}` in your preamble.  Basically, you can redefine it to be whatever symbol you want.

```
\renewcommand\qedsymbol{}%% just resolves to nothing

\renewcommand\qedsymbol{$\cap$}%% gives you an upsidedown U (intersection)
```

Not sure why you'd want to redefine it this wa; I  just provided the example to suggest the possibilities.

To find documentation on the this, look at the documentation for the `amsthm` package.

If you only want the change to apply locally, you can surround the `\renewcommand\qebsymbol`  and the environment in curly brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

A proof environment without \verb-\qed-.
{\renewcommand\qedsymbol{}%%
\begin{proof}
Is there any knowledge in the world which is so certain that no
reasonable man could doubt it? This question, which at first sight might
not seem difficult, is really one of the most difficult that can
be asked. When we have realized the obstacles in the way of a
straightforward and confident answer, we shall be well launched on the
study of philosophy--for philosophy is merely the attempt to answer
such ultimate questions, not carelessly and dogmatically, as we do in
ordinary life and even in the sciences, but critically, after exploring
all that makes such questions puzzling, and after realizing all the
vagueness and confusion that underlie our ordinary ideas.
\end{proof}}%%

A proof environment with \verb-\qed- (default behavior)
\begin{proof}
In daily life, we assume as certain many things which, on a closer
scrutiny, are found to be so full of apparent contradictions that only a
great amount of thought enables us to know what it is that we really may
believe. In the search for certainty, it is natural to begin with our
present experiences, and in some sense, no doubt, knowledge is to be
derived from them. But any statement as to what it is that our immediate
experiences make us know is very likely to be wrong. It seems to me that
I am now sitting in a chair, at a table of a certain shape, on which I
see sheets of paper with writing or print. By turning my head I see out
of the window buildings and clouds and the sun. I believe that the sun
is about ninety-three million miles from the earth; that it is a hot
globe many times bigger than the earth; that, owing to the earth's
rotation, it rises every morning, and will continue to do so for an
indefinite time in the future. I believe that, if any other normal
person comes into my room, he will see the same chairs and tables and
books and papers as I see, and that the table which I see is the same as
the table which I feel pressing against my arm. All this seems to be
so evident as to be hardly worth stating, except in answer to a man who
doubts whether I know anything. Yet all this may be reasonably doubted,
and all of it requires much careful discussion before we can be sure
that we have stated it in a form that is wholly true.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The recommended way to remove the qed symbol from a single proof is to input `\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{}` *after* `\begin{proof}`.  This is documented in the `amsthm` user guide (`texdoc amsthdoc`).  `proof` is a "closed" environment, so no additional scoping is needed.